# replace part of a string ' for \' not working

Tags: python, mysql

I'm extracting data from a API to insert it in a MySQL table. I found that some rows have columns with single quotes (') values, and give problems with the insertion code to Mysql. I want to replace them with a escape value (\'), but for some reason my replace code is not working

```
import requests
import math
import pymysql
import string
from datetime import date, timedelta

#replace invalid characters with scapes values

print (type(calls[b][17]))
print (type(calls[b][18]))



print (calls[b][17])
print (calls[b][18])


if calls[b][17] is not None:
    calls[b][17] = calls[b][17].replace("'","\'")

if calls[b][18] is not None:
    calls[b][18] = calls[b][18].replace("'","\'")

print (calls[b][17])
print (calls[b][18])
```

the result is

> ### class types

### original values

"Cecile Denier d'Aprigny" <+33179976110>

Cecile

Denier d'Aprigny

Cecile Denier d'Aprigny

### replaced values

"Cecile Denier d'Aprigny" <+33179976110>

Cecile

Denier d'Aprigny

Cecile Denier d'Aprigny

### final statement

INSERT INTO thinking_phone_data  VALUES ('e912be49-bfd3-4454-8679-c53503eecfd2','+33179976110','+33170709949','2016-01-19 09:27:25.0','2016-01-19 09:27:33.0','2016-01-19 09:31:19.0','234','226','Answered','0','0','"Cecile Denier d'Aprigny" <+33179976110>','3 Mundi','3 Mundi','team3','cdenier@3mundi.com','Cecile','Denier d'Aprigny','Cecile Denier d'Aprigny','Paris Office','None','None','None','None','None','None','None','None')

I want my replaced values to be

"Cecile Denier d\'Aprigny" <+33179976110>

Cecile

Denier d\'Aprigny

Cecile Denier d'Aprigny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I need just to explain the question to clear my head. Just need to add all correct escape values

the solution is

```
            if calls[b][11] is not None:
                calls[b][11] = calls[b][11].replace('\'','\\\'')
```